# Android : ConstraintLayout support RTL

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I gone through many solutions but i didn't understand the how to make design support to RTL Using `ConstraintLayout` in android.

Comment: Use "start" and "end" constraints instead of "left" and "right" constraints (e.g., `layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf`), the same as you would with `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just replace the constraints from `Left` to `Start` & `Right` to `End` ,

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf = layout_constraintStart_toEndOf
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf = layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf = layout_constraintStart_toStartOf
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf = layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf
```

I am sure it will work perfectly for you,

**See my Paradigm** `item_list.xml`

LTR Screenshot

[image: English]

RTL Screenshot

[image: RTL]

**Note:** I hope you already added this line `android:supportsRtl="true"`in `AndroidManifest.xml` & some placed you need to remove textAlignment property. Alignment will surely work with **Arabic** text.

**Updated:**

> > It's better practices to add/put both properties to avoid api level version support,

```
layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf
layout_constraintStart_toEndOf

layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf
layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf

layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf
layout_constraintStart_toStartOf

layout_constraintRight_toRightOf
layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf
```

Comment: it seems working but i am not using any `textAlignment` property still it shows me text on left side for **RTL**

Comment: Ohh nice comment when you set **Arabic** text to `TextView` it will set automatically from Right to left but make sure you are not setting width constant anywhere.

Comment: Will constraint start/end works in api 16?Why not add both left/right and start/end to support old and new versions?

Answer (score 1):

Do following things,

1. Find & Replace `Left` with `Start`
2. Find & replace `Right` with `End`

If you are using `leftDrawing` or `rightDrawing` still need to replace it by `startDrawing` & `endDrawing`

Same for padding too,

and don't forget to add following line in `AndroidManifest` file,

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```